# Join Multiple Transactions Across Instances of EF Connections

Tags: entity-framework-4, transactions

I have the following setup in my Data Layer

```cs
namespace DAL
{
    public abstract class BaseDalObj:IDisposable
    {
        protected Auto.Entities entities;
        public BaseDalObj()
        {
            entities= new Auto.Entities();
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }
    public class Class1: BaseDalObj
    {
        public void Save(object a)
        {
            entities.SaveItem(a);
        }
    }

    public class Class2: BaseDalObj
    {
        public void Save(object b)
        {
            entities.SaveItem(b);
        }
    }
}
namespace Business
{
    public class BusinessLL
    {
        public Object a,b;
        public BusinessDAL()
        {
            a = new Object();
            b = new Object();
        }

        public void Save()
        {
                using(var dbObj1 = new DAL.Class1())
                {
                    dbObj1.Save(a);
                    using(var dbObj2 = new DAL.Class2())
                    {
                        dbObj2.Save(b);
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

what I would like is some way to call both Save functions but within the same TransactionScope.

I have no idea how i can do this using EF. I have looked into using the TransactionScope Class but I cannot get to grips with how it works.

I have been looking at using the `entities.Connection.BeginTransaction()` but that returns a `DbTransaction` and `TransactionScope` only accepts a type `Transaction` Class

Any help or pointers that can point me in the right way would really help.

Comment: What exactly did you not understand on using `TransactionScope`?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka I dont understand how to get the transaction from one instance of entities to join onto the TransactionScope as if i call entities.Connection.BeginTransaction() it returns a DBTransaction but TransactionScope only Accepts a Transaction Class. 
Am I right in thinking if i call Transaction.Current i will get the Transaction created using entities.Connection.BeginTransaction()

Comment: TransactionScope will handle transaction creation itself. You don't need to do anything but when you execute it on two contexts simultaneously it will most probably start distributed transaction and that requires MSDTC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is an ambient transaction present when opening a connection the connection will automatically enlist into this transaction. This applies to the ObjectContext too - when you call ObjectContext.SaveChanges it will automatically enlist the connection into the ambient transaction. 
Therefore, I think this should work:

```
using(var transaction = new TransactionScope)
{
   using(var class1 = new Class1())
   {
       class1.Save(x);
   }

   using(var class2 = new Class2())
   {
       class2.Save(y);
   }

   transaction.Complete();
}
```

Comment: i will give that a try and let you know what happens

Comment: Hi, i have tried what you have suggested and i think this is the way for me to go but the function SaveItem is an SP which is handling the custom save part. What I am trying to ask is will the TransactionScope object Create the Transaction that can be used in the DB. 
Sorry for not understanding how this stuff all fits in together. 
my SP looks like this http://rusanu.com/2009/06/11/exception-handling-and-nested-transactions/

Comment: I found that it was failing because i didnt remove 1 of the commit statements in one of my old SP's, but once i traced down all the commit statements and the rollback statements it worked perfectly thank you so much for all your help

Comment: I am glad that you were able to figure this out!